# Full Outer Joins In PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, outer-join

I've created a table of `student`s with columns `student_id` as primary key, 
`student_name` and `gender`.

I've an another table `gender` which consists of `gender_id` and `gender`.

`gender_id` in `student` refers to table `gender`.

Tables data looks like this:

**Student table**

```
STUDENT_ID  STUDENT_NAME    GENDER
1            Ajith           1
2            Alan            1
3            Ann             2
4            Alexa           2
5            Amith           1
6            Nisha           2
7            Rathan          1
8            Rebecca         2
9            asdf            null
10           asd             null     
11           dbss            null
```

**Gender Table**

```
GENDER_ID   GENDER
1           Male
2           Female
3           Others
```

My query and its result

```
SELECT  S.STUDENT_NAME,
        G.GENDER
FROM  STUDENTS S
FULL OUTER JOIN GENDER G ON G.GENDER_ID = S.GENDER
```

result is giving with 12 rows including the **Others** value from the gender table.

```
STUDENT_ID  STUDENT_NAME    GENDER
1             Ajith         Male
2             Alan          Male
3             Ann           Female
4             Alexa         Female
5             Amith         Male
6             Nisha         Female
7             Rathan        Male
8             Rebecca       Female
                            Others
9             asdf  
10            asd   
11            dbss
```

I'm trying to restrict a particular `student_id`:

```
SELECT  S.STUDENT_ID,
        S.STUDENT_NAME,
        G.GENDER
FROM  STUDENTS S
FULL OUTER JOIN GENDER G ON G.GENDER_ID = S.GENDER
WHERE S.STUDENT_ID <> 11;
```

now the the total number of the rows are reduced to 10.

```
STUDENT_ID  STUDENT_NAME    GENDER
1           Ajith           Male
2           Alan            Male
3           Ann             Female
4           Alexa           Female
5           Amith           Male
6           Nisha           Female
7           Rathan          Male
8           Rebecca         Female
9           asdf    
10          asd
```

Why has the one row with **Others** Values disappeared from the second select query?
I'm trying to find the cause of this issue.

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a possibly NULL-extended column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns an OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]--clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) & desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second select query returns all rows where student_id is different (`<>`) from 11.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `NULL <> 11` is not `TRUE`, but `NULL`, and only rows where the condition is `TRUE` are included in the result.

You'd have to write something like

```
WHERE s.student_id IS DISTINCT FROM 11
```

Comment: thanks for the information.